# App runs fine on phones, crashes on tablets

Tags: android, android-logcat

My app runs fine on phone crashes on start up on tablets. It runs fine on my phone running 2.3.7 and my sister's phone running 4.0.3. But it crashes on my 10.1" tablet running 4.0.4. I tried it on a Nexus 7 AVD running 4.2 and it crashes there too.

This is the Log

```
12-26 23:11:55.350: E/Trace(845): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-26 23:11:55.350: W/Trace(845): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-26 23:11:55.350: W/Trace(845): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-26 23:11:55.350: W/Trace(845): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-26 23:11:55.560: W/Trace(845): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-26 23:11:55.560: W/Trace(845): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-26 23:11:56.741: D/dalvikvm(845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 217K, 12% free 2635K/2984K, paused 70ms+14ms, total 139ms
12-26 23:11:56.751: D/dalvikvm(845): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
12-26 23:11:56.813: D/dalvikvm(845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 14% free 2666K/3084K, paused 52ms, total 53ms
12-26 23:11:56.821: I/dalvikvm-heap(845): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.333MB for 635812-byte allocation
12-26 23:11:56.881: D/dalvikvm(845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 3286K/3708K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
12-26 23:11:56.931: D/dalvikvm(845): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 3287K/3708K, paused 9ms+3ms, total 52ms
12-26 23:11:56.931: D/dalvikvm(845): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
12-26 23:11:56.931: I/dalvikvm-heap(845): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.811MB for 500416-byte allocation
12-26 23:11:57.011: D/dalvikvm(845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 3775K/4200K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
12-26 23:11:57.223: D/AndroidRuntime(845): Shutting down VM
12-26 23:11:57.223: W/dalvikvm(845): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.brandsonicinc.brandsonic.web.mobile/com.brandsonicinc.brandsonic.web.mobile.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.brandsonicinc.brandsonic.web.mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-26 23:11:57.231: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  ... 11 more
12-26 23:12:02.487: W/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1835: [1226/231202:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1835)] Destroying invalid entry.
12-26 23:12:02.500: E/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1107: [1226/231202:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1107)] Critical error found -8
12-26 23:12:02.820: W/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [1226/231202:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
12-26 23:12:02.820: W/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [1226/231202:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
12-26 23:12:02.840: W/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [1226/231202:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
12-26 23:12:02.881: W/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [1226/231202:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
12-26 23:12:02.966: E/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/entry_impl.cc:904: [1226/231202:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(904)] Failed to save user data
12-26 23:12:02.971: E/chromium(845): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/entry_impl.cc:904: [1226/231202:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(904)] Failed to save user data
12-26 23:12:04.361: I/Process(845): Sending signal. PID: 845 SIG: 9
```

Please help this is very frustrating. It used to run fine on tablets. Could it have something to do with the layouts?

Comment: Post your code in `onCreate` from `MainActivity`, and make sure you include line 84.

Comment: It most likely has to do with layouts. Do you have different layouts such as layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge? If so, make sure that all the disparate xml files have the same elements. You're mostly likely failing on a findById result.

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.brandsonicinc.brandsonic.web.mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)"

Comment: Where is your xml files ? in layout or layout-* folder ?

Comment: the problem may be with your xml file

Comment: @Segadude Post your activity code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put all your xml files in `layout` folder and no need to remove it from other if it already there.

If xml files are in folders like `layout-sw600dp` then the device will fail to load the specified xml file if screen width is less than 600dp. this is just example in your case it may be different

Comment: I have layout, layout-sw600dp, and layout-sw720dp folders. I had made a change to the activity_main.xml in layout but didn't make the change in the other two folders. I moved to activity_main.xml to the other folders and it now works again.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your log, there is a bug on finding directory, have you use some directory method, to retrieve file from a particular location, tablet have internal storage instead of sd card might be problem in that.

But I can better understand if you post the code.